# Recognize CSS orientation in iFrame

Tags: css, iframe, orientation, message

Is it possible that an iframe can recognize the orientation of its parent website? At the moment the css media query is only working at my parent site.

I tried to fix this issue by sending a post message to my iframe and change the linked css file with javascript:

parent site:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){
  var iframe = document.getElementById("plan_iframe");
  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({orientation: window.orientation}, iframe.src);
}, false)
```

iframe:

```
<link id="changing_css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=""/>

[...]

window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
  var newOrientationValue = e.data.orientation;
  if(newOrientationValue == 90 || newOrientationValue == -90){
    document.getElementById('changing_css').href="css/vertretung_ios_landscape.css";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('changing_css').href="css/vertretung_ios_portrait.css";
  }
}, false)
```

This fix is very slow because javascript needs some time to load the file "onorientationchange" and apply the changes.

How does css recognizes the orientation?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Did you find any solutions? I'm trying to detect the device orientation from a media query in the CSS for an iframe.

Comment: As my Website is an iOS optimized website, I changed the media query to
`@media screen and (min-width: 900px)`.
This is the fastest and easiest workaround.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had control over the parent window. I solved this by putting an additional media query on the parent container's iFrame styles. Turns out that the CSS media query for orientation simply goes by whichever property is greater. For example...

An iFrame of greater height will render in portrait orientation. `width: 400px; height: 600px;`

An iFrame of greater width will render in landscape orientation. `width: 600px; height: 400px;`